# 500 Internal server error after finished paypal configuration

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, error, onepage-checkout

Im trying to setup my first magento store, im working with magento community v1.7.0.2 with custom theme and modules. Last week after finished with the payment options i worked for one hour wihtout any issue. Then i was edditing some .cvs files in order to translate some words and then i got this messege.

```
Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Checkout_Controller_Action' not found in xxxxx/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php on line 29
```

I get this messege when im on my my shoping cart webpage and press the PROCEED TO CHECKOUT button, i have tried different stuff like:

- set files and directories permision
- edit .htaccess file

I found some info about paypal express checkout bugs or issues with magento and custom themes but cant find anything to solve my problem. Thx in advance guys

Comment: Make sure this file still exists `app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Controller/Action.php`

Comment: Check whether you have correctly declared the class name in that class file.